# jQuery Datatable - On pdf export, upon giving a new line to data, how to avoid <br/> that gets print on each new line?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, newline

I have a datatable which have bunch of data. I have 2 buttons for PDF and CSV. I have a comma seperated string in one of the column. I want to split and display with a new line when I export the PDF.

Eg: data = a, b, c, d;

Expected output on PDF and CSV

```
a
b
c
d
```

Current Output:

```
a
<br/>b
<br/>c
<br/>d
```

My code looks like following:

```
exportOptions: {
        format: {
          body: function (data, column, row) {
            return column === 2 ?
              data.replace(/,/g, '\r\n') :
              data;
          }
        }
      }
```

I have tried everything. So far nothing helps.

```
/n /r/n <br> <br />
```

Comment: what datatable library is it? There are 1000s of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic working example of what you're trying to do

```html
<table id="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1,2,3,4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$('#table').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'csv',
    exportOptions: {
      format: {
        body: function(data, row, column, node) {
          return data.replaceAll(',', '\r\n');
        }
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k8rgL4cy/)

This is not much different from what you're trying to do (except maybe for the use of the easier `replaceAll` instead of `replace`). That does not explain what's wrong with your code but it may help you fix it anyway.

Comment: Updated fiddle including all required scripts to include a `pdf` button, SO snippet blocks downloads, so no snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/vus2x6z5/